# Haskell: From Vectors to Unboxed Vectors

Tags: haskell, vector

Today I was working in transforming some code that used `Data.Vector` to a more "memory efficient" `Data.Vector.Unboxed` when I suddenly realized a missing instance.

If I do this in `ghci`:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
V.singleton V.empty :: V.Vector (V.Vector Int)
[[]]
```

That is correct, Vector was printed correctly. However, if I try the same with `Vector.Unboxed`:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as VU
:set -XFlexibleContexts
VU.singleton VU.empty :: VU.Vector (VU.Vector Int)
```

I get the error:

```
<interactive>:10:1: error:
    • No instance for (VU.Unbox (VU.Vector Int))
        arising from a use of ‘VU.singleton’
    • In the expression:
          VU.singleton VU.empty :: VU.Vector (VU.Vector Int)
      In an equation for ‘it’:
          it = VU.singleton VU.empty :: VU.Vector (VU.Vector Int)
```

Which drives me to the question, how do I correctly implement an unboxed vector of vectors?

---

---

Side note:

The objective I was trying to reach was a generic `splitChunks` function, with the basic premise of splitting a vector into sub vectors of fixed size, a very primitive implementation using common vectors was as follows:

```
-- With an arbitrary vector and a positive integer of known size it will create a vector that has splitted the original into sections. Example:
-- vec = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
-- size = 4
-- result = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10]]
splitChunks :: V.Vector p -> Int -> V.Vector (V.Vector p)
splitChunks vec size
    | size <= 0 = V.empty
    | otherwise = fst $ until condition opr (V.empty, vec)
    where condition = V.null . snd
          opr (x, y) = let (l, r) = V.splitAt size y in (V.snoc x l, r)
```

Then, when I tried to move from Vector to Vector.Unboxed, I got the same problem as described before.

Comment: You can't! Unboxed values have to be fixed size

Comment: I updated the post making it explicit the desired type I would like to have, in this case ```Vector (Vector Int)```. That would mean, Int is unboxed and the size is known.

Comment: So the outer vector will be a boxed vector. `V.Vector (VU.Vector Int)`

Comment: While the size of `Int` is known, the size of `VU.Vector Int` is not because the number of Int elements in the vector is dynamic.  You could have a static length vector.  You could use the vector from `fixed-vector` for fixed size unboxed vectors.

Comment: I will check the library ```fixed-vector``` and see if that fits to the action I am trying to perform.